# Build instructions for pygobject on OSX

Tags: macos, macports, homebrew, pygobject

How do you build pygobject (GTK+ 3 in Python with introspection) on OSX? I'm not a mac user--I'm hoping to help my colleagues run an application I wrote for Linux on their mac books.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found these instructions on the GNOME wiki: [GTK+/OSX/Building](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GTK+/OSX/Building) and [GTK+/OSX/Python](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK+/OSX/Python)